# PrimeNG Angular carousel doesn;t look right

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use the carousel component to display entry fees for national parks.  For some reason, the carousel doesn't look like the demo on the website.

```
    <p-carousel [value]="parkData.entranceFees" [numVisible]="3" [numScroll]="3" [circular]="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <h2>Entrance Fees</h2>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-fee pTemplate="item">
            {{ fee.title }}
        </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
```

This is what the page component looks like within my page:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPEg.png)

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: I have one: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.  I have the carousel wrapped in a div: <div id="carousel" *ngIf="parkData.entranceFees[0].cost != '0.00'">

Comment: I just went and fixed the error by giving parkData.entranceFees an intial value of 0.00 until it is re-assigned by http response.  The console error is gone, but the visual result has not changed.

Comment: Do you think it'd be possible to reproduce this in a StackBlitz? Personally, it's hard to see without the full picture

Comment: Mabye, It's a pretty big project.  Let me see

Comment: I don't think ill be able to.  I've got local sql servers, backend, etc. that is not web accessible yet

Comment: What's strange is they the button's function, they just don't look like buttons.  And there's that weird looking thing at the bottom

Comment: Apart from installing the NPM module, you need to include the styles too. Could you please confirm that you have incorporated styles too?

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't have the required CSS theme in my angular.json file.  I don't know why it didn't alert me with an error message, but now that I added a valid theme, it's working like a charm.